# Creating a DateTimeOffset in a Timezone Different to the One the User is In

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

I want to create a `DateTimeOffset` which is the date that I specify, but in another timezone.
There's a bit of a catch to this. 2 things:
-1- I am NOT in the TimeZone in which I am interested i.e. it is NOT my local timezone.
-2- At the time of writing, the offset in Auckland is non-standard due to Daylight savings. Normally it is 12. right now, it is 13.

So, my attempt was as follows:

```
var someDate = new DateTimeOffset(selectedDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("New Zealand Standard Time").BaseUtcOffset);
```

This did not work because `BaseUtcOffset` always returns the standard offset i.e. 12, not 13.

How do I got about this.
Remember, before suggesting conversions to UTC etc. that I am not in that TimeZone. So any date I create on my computer will be in the `E. Australia Daylight Time` timezone, not `New Zealand Standard Time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to get the correct offset on the date of whatever `selectedDate` is:

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("New Zealand Standard Time").GetUtcOffset(selectedDate)
```

If you feed that today's date, it returns 13.

It's probably best if `selectedDate` is UTC. I don't know what effect it would have if it's a local time.

Comment: It's a strange API. Not sure why handing it a date works. I guess that's why Noda time was built. But thanks.

Comment: It can't give you the correct offset without knowing the date you want the offset for, since it's different today than it is in August. If you just want the current offset, you can feed it `DateTime.UtcNow`.